# can we pass a list to a permission_required?

Tags: python, django

I need to check a few permissions in a class based view.
is there a way to pass a list (multiple permissions) to a permission_required?
(we were include a PermissionRequiredMixin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply pass an iterable to permission_required. For example:

```
  permission_required = ('polls.add_choice', 'polls.change_choice')
```